# Why is this giving me "list index out of range"? I'm trying to find names in a list and names can be two words long or more

Tags: python, list

```
_ID = "000001234"
f = open("Players.txt", "r")
allLines = f.readlines()
nameList = [[] for i in range(1,len(allLines))]
for i in range(0,len(allLines)):
    splitLine = allLines[i].split()
    l = len(splitLine)
    for name in range(1,l-3):
        nameList[i].append(splitLine[name])
    #print(nameList[i])

for i in range(0, len(allLines)):
    splitLine = allLines[i].split()
    if splitLine[0] == _ID:
        print(nameList[i])
        break

f.close()
```

Data:

```
Player ID                      Player Name          Age   Height(cm)   Weight(kg)
   000000001               Aaron Appindangoye           26      183         84.8
   000000002                  Aaron Cresswell           28      170         66.2
   000000003                      Aaron Doran           26      170         73.9
   000000004                    Aaron Galindo           36      183         89.8
   000000005                     Aaron Hughes           38      183         69.9
   000000006                       Aaron Hunt           31      183         73.0
```

Comment: Can you post the full error?

Comment: You need: `range(0, len(allLines) - 1)`. But much simpler might be to remove the header line at the very beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Your `nameList` has a smaller length than a length of `allLines`:

```
>>> len(allLines)
>>> 7
```

however,

```
>>> len(nameList)
>>> 6
```

try `nameList = [[] for i in range(0,len(allLines))]`

```
_ID = "000001234"
f = open("Players.txt", "r")
allLines = f.readlines()
nameList = [[] for i in range(0,len(allLines))]
for i in range(1,len(allLines)):
    splitLine = allLines[i].split()
    l = len(splitLine)
    for name in range(1,l-3):
        nameList[i].append(splitLine[name])
    #print(nameList[i])

for i in range(0, len(allLines)):
    splitLine = allLines[i].split()
    if splitLine[0] == _ID:
        print(nameList[i])
        break

f.close()  
nameList = [ii for ii in nameList[1:]]
```

Comment: Now it gives: _splitLine = allLines[i].split()
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list_